# Is there any way to use dedicated graphic card for external monitor instead of integrated Microsoft Basic Display Adapter on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, resolution, vga, external-display

I have a very tough problem and I couldn't find a solution yet.
I am having an Old PC (Acer Aspire 7750G) which it has still good hardware capabilities. But its north or south bridge (I don't remember exactly) has corrupted 3 years ago, than its USB-3 and HDMI ports are not working. Then, 2 weeks ago its monitor chip and 17" built-in monitor have corrupted too. Finally I've decided to make it ALL-In-Out PC (laptop without built-in monitor and lid but using external Lenovo monitor. Note that: drivers of monitor is installed correctly and it supports 1920x1080 resolution over VGA). I've removed the lid and internal monitor from their sockets and connect external monitor over VGA port.

But this time I've faced with resolution and color depth problems. After installing Windows 10, I am having some problems below;

In the Device Manager:
I only can see the one monitor (Lenovo), that's normal.
I only can see the one display adapter (AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series), that's normal.

But when I try to set monitor resolution and color depth, while monitor supports 1920x1080 - 32bit, Windows 10 shows me the wrong resolutions with just 8-bit depth (also most of resolutions are not usable by monitor and monitor gives an error like: "unsupported resolution" then reverts back to previous resolution).
Another problem is, when I look the Display Settings > Advanced Display Settings, Windows shows me that;
Select a display drop-down menu -> Display 1 : Wired Display (only one option)
Display Information section -> Display 1: connected to the Microsoft Basic Display Driver

My question is that, is it possible to attach my AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M Series display adapter to external VGA monitor?

**Notes**:
My PC is a bit old and it has no modern BIOS (InsydeH20) and there is no any settings for display adapters etc.
I installed the Intel Chipset drivers and also I tried to I install AMD Catalyst drivers but when I install the AMD Catalyst driver, surprisingly  my monitor and display driver corrupts (I was be able to install Catalyst drivers when original built-in monitor was working).
I didn't add any screenshot because my Win10 is Turkish.

Comment: The only way NOT to use the basic adapter is to install the drivers for the GPU. Have you done that? If your running an OS the drivers that have been released does not support then you are out of luck

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your quick reply. Windows 10 already recognized my display device but yes, I've installed the AMD Radeon 6600M and 6700M driver moreover too. Interesting part is, my display device is recognized correctly in device manager but my external monitor is attached to the MS driver (even though MS driver is not visible in device manager).

Comment: Mobile GPUs lack the hardware to directly connect to monitors. The monitor will always be driven by the iGPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its not possible. Your dedicated GPU is a [AMD Radeon HD 6650M](https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-hd-6650m.c326)  :

> This device has no display connectivity, as it is not designed to have
> monitors connected to it. Rather it is intended for use in
> laptop/notebooks and will use the output of the host mobile device.

This is normal for a laptop: the monitor will always be driven by the iGPU.

As for the bit depth, over VGA connector the output is analog, not digital, and the maximum is a total of 16bit. While 3x 8bit to VGA translation is standard, I don't think 3x 10bit to VGA will work, and anyway it would not change the color gamut that can be transmitted over the analog cable.
Some references for VGA

- [complete guide](https://blog.ugreen.com/vga-connector/)
- [is it possible to get 10bit through vga?](https://www.elevenforum.com/t/is-it-possible-to-get-10-bit-or-more-color-depth-through-vga.17029/)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array)

I also would suspect that your system never supported 10bit. The [HDMI version for the Acer Aspire 7750G is 1.4a](https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/590082/is-acer-aspire-7750g-hdmi-specs-hdmi1-4-or-not) which [does not support 10bit over Intel graphics](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000057279/graphics.html).

**Edit**
You might want to install the [driver for the intel gpu](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download-center/home.html) and maybe also the [intel graphics command center](https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9PLFNLNT3G5G?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab&hl=en-us&gl=US) for best experience and tweaks to your iGPU